# Can one combine ancient and modern Greek with Babel?

Tags: babel, polyglossia, greek

Using Polyglossia, it's possible to use ancient and modern Greek in a single document. Unfortunately, [Polyglossia's support for Greek is broken under LuaLaTeX](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/55). Is is possible to accomplish this using Babel?

According to the [babel-greek documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/greek/babel-greek.pdf), `polutonikogreek` and `greek` cannot be used in the same document; it doesn't explicitly say that there is no way to mix ancient and modern Greek, but it seems that the `\usepackage[greek.ancient,english]{babel}` or `\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}` options can only be used in a preamble.

Comment: It is possible but not with the current implementation of babel-greek. You would have to write e.g. a ancientgreek.ldf and sort out the commands you need. You could ask the babel-greek maintainers if they could options for this.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I suspect it would be easier to fix Polyglossia, but I don't entirely understand the nature of the bug there.

Comment: I don't understand the bug either, but you can activate the hyphenation by using e.g. `\selectlanguage{greek}\hyphenrules{polygreek}` (which uses babel code to load the pattern). But imho it would be better to switch to babel and contact the babel-greek maintainer, they are more active currently than polyglossia.

Comment: It's unfortunate, since Polyglossia is still more advanced in many respects, and it's also easier to understand its development, since it has a repository on GitHub. I keep hoping that the two packages will merge!

Answer (score 5):

Using Monotonic Greek, Polytonic Greek and Ancient Greek at the same time in `babel` is possible, but you have to resort to the `ini` locale files, because the basic `ldf` style still has this limitation.

In the following example, the option `provide*=*` means ‘load all declared languages as `ini` locale files’. I’ve colorized the fonts to show the different languages. It works with both `xetex` and `luatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polytonicgreek, ancientgreek, greek, provide*=*]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}[Color=993300]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}[Color=339900]{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

Greek text (monotonic): \figurename, \alsoname.

\selectlanguage{polytonicgreek}

Polytonic Greek: \figurename, \alsoname.

\selectlanguage{ancientgreek}

Ancient Greek: \figurename, \alsoname.

\end{document}
```

[image]