# What is the most up-to-date indicated/suggested way to typeset Greek?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, greek, font-encodings

I typically type on an English keyboard, but I use a Greek keyboard when it comes to typing Greek characters. I have my personal workaround through the `pdfLaTeX` engine, but as LaTeX evolves it seems (at least to me) the focus tends towards the `XeLaTeX` and/or `LuaTeX` engines more and more. I would want to switch to these engines, but in the past I had no luck (more like disaster) with Greek fonts. So, I am wondering how to transition and what is the best recent/modern "official" way to typeset in Greek at whim.

Here is what I typically need:

- use the Greek and English keyboards interchangeably without specifying a language change
- type Greek in math-mode (along side English)
- type Greek in text-mode (along side English)
- type a document entirely in Greek (with occasional English)
- (optional) be able to type a Greek semicolon (άνω τελεία / ano teleia / upper dot): unicode -> `U+0387`
- (optional) define commands using Greek literals, e.g. `\newcommand{\εντολή}{εντολή}`

(Okay, this last one is very farfetched, but it'd be cool if it was possible.)

I understand that specific math environments like `proof` or `abstract` may need to be changed manually in the preamble, but this is fine since that's a one-time thing.

For good measure, I'll post here the code I've been using for far to serve as a reference. Of course, the first few lines is the important part. Note that this code only works with `pdfLaTeX` --- save for the magic commments:

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} %%%%%%%%%%% The latter language is the default. DO NOT change the language order.
\usepackage{alphabeta} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{textcase} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is needed when amsart class is loaded to avoid errors in the title.
\usepackage[style=greek]{csquotes} %%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This code redefines the name macros.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Comment the following lines if this not needed.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addto\captionsenglish{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% The babel necessitates the use of \addto\caption<language>
    \renewcommand*\abstractname{{Περίληψη}}%% [article/report class]
    \renewcommand*\appendixname{{Παράρτημα}}%
    \renewcommand*\bibname{{Βιβλιογραφία}}%%% [book/report class] %% does not work with biblatex package
    \renewcommand*\chaptername{{Κεφάλαιο}}%%% [book/report class]
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{{Περιεχόμενα}}%
    \renewcommand*\figurename{{Εικόνα}}%%%%%%
    \renewcommand*\indexname{{Ευρετήριο}}%%%%
    \renewcommand*\listfigurename{{Περιοχόμενα Εικόνων}}%
    \renewcommand*\listtablename{{Περιεχόμενα Πινάκων}}%
    \renewcommand*\partname{{Μέρος}}%%%%%%%%%
    \renewcommand*\prefacename{{Πρόλογος}}%%%
    \renewcommand*\proofname{{Απόδειξη}}%%%%%
    \renewcommand*\refname{{Αναφορές}}%%%%%%% [article class] %% does not work with biblatex package
    \renewcommand*\tablename{{Πίνακας}}%%%%%%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Optional definitions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section] %%%%%%
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Λήμμα} %%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Πρόταση} %%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Πόρισμα} %%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Ορισμός} %%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{rem}[theorem]{Σημείωση} %%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{rems}[theorem]{Σημειώσεις} %%%%%%
\newtheorem{ex}[theorem]{Πράδειγμα} %%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: A couple of links: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579780/use-of-greek-language-without-textlatin-textgreek-each-word/579813#579813 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294828/can-one-combine-ancient-and-modern-greek-with-babel/614278#614278 . See also https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-greek.html .

Comment: @JavierBezos These link seem very useful, thanks! I only get the impression that things are still "under construction" in a way.
I assume GitHub is where the latest updates are posted?

Comment:  I’m not sure what “under construction” means here, but it’s certainly not under construction in the usual sense. `babel` is being actively maintained and developed, that’s all, with new features being added regularly, like most programs, including LaTeX itself. The latest stable release is available on CTAN.

Comment: @JavierBezos Yeah, I simply meant that there are still things being developed which are not optimal yet (for example hyphenation).

By the way, is there (or will there be) command using Greek characters? (see my last dot)

Comment: What’s the problem with hyphenation?

Comment: I haven't encountered any problem myself. On the GitHub link it simply says it works only with LuaTex

Comment: Features marked with _Only luatex_ usually work only with that engine just because there are intrinsic limitations in `xetex` and `pdftex`.